# Webscraping call in python returns empty values

Tags: beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm trying to get the last traded prices (LTP) from different commodities from MCX website https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/market-watch in python 2.0. Following is the code I'm using.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = 'https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/market-watch'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'ltp green ltpcenter'})
```

But when I run the code, I get empty values. I suspect the website queries some other web server for the values, because when I look at the source of the web page, I do not see the last traded prices there. Can anyone please help me how to get the price data into python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the below code gets all the market data displayed on that page, extract whatever you want from the json response.

```
import requests
url = "https://www.mcxindia.com/backpage.aspx/GetMarketWatch"

headers = {
    "Host": "www.mcxindia.com",
    "Origin": "https://www.mcxindia.com",
    "X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest",
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.81 Safari/537.36",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
"Referer": "https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/market-watch",
"Accept": "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01",  
}


resp  = requests.post(url, headers = headers)
market_data = resp.json()
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to process the JS, you can use selenium to load JS, see the code below.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait as wait
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://www.mcxindia.com/market-data/market-watch")
wait(driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(
        (By.XPATH, '//*[@class="symbol chnge-perc right5"]')))
source = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(source, 'html.parser')
soup.findAll('div',attrs={'class':'ltp green ltpcenter'})
print soup
```